# Always wrapping <p> text to window when horizontal scrollbar appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The text in my HTML file wraps fine until the window is resized to be smaller than a table/image with a static width. Once a scrollbar appears, the text stops wrapping.

I need all `<p>` elements to continue wrapping to the window size when the horizontal scrollbar appears to accommodate for static tables/images, but can't for the life of me find any documentation on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Andy, would setting the CSS overflow property help?  You can make it scrollable or hide the text when overflowing occurs.  See: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

```
<p style="overflow:auto"></p>
```

Setting it to auto will show scrollbars only when the text "overflows" the boundaries.

Comment: No luck.  I have everything contained in the body set to overflow: auto, but since the tables I use have a static width, that is acting as the minimum width for the document. If I have a 500px wide table, I want to be able to resize the window to 100px and have the table overflow (horizontal scrollbar appears) but have the text outside of the tables continue wrapping to the document width. I'm thinking i'll have to use javascript to created floated divs for those '<p>' elements

Comment: Interesting.  What browser are you using (and what version of the browser)?  Also are you rendering in quirks mode or standard mode?  One thing I do sometimes to see how the page is rendering, put `style="1px solid red"` (and change the color to green, blue, etc for different elements) on the different elements, including the page body.  I think in standards mode it shouldn't be pushing out the width of the whole page, just overflowing beyond the width.  So your text shouldn't be using the width of the table. (if that makes sense)

Comment: Just realized the cause - the text in not contained in the root of <body>, instead, inside of <body> is a 3 row table with a header, the "main" row, and a footer. -_-;